# How to alternate capitalizations with RegEX?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, capitalization, alternating

I need to change a sentence to have alternating capitalizations! Having trouble making it ignore the spacebar inputs...

input: `the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`
output: `tHe QuIcK bRoWn FoX jUmPs OvEr ThE lAzY dOg`

I tried the following:

input: `([\w\s])([\w\s]?)`
output: `upper(\1)\2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import re
text = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
print( re.sub(r"(\S)(\s*)(\S)", lambda x: f'{x.group(1).lower()}{x.group(2)}{x.group(3).upper()}', text) )
# tHe QuIcK bRoWn FoX jUmPs OvEr ThE lAzY dOg
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/18HPDw).

The `(\S)(\s*)(\S)` regex matches and captures a non-whitespace char into Group 1, then captures zero or more whitespaces into Group 2 and then captures any whitespace into Group 3. The `f'{x.group(1).lower()}{x.group(2)}{x.group(3).upper()}'` replacement concatenates a lowercase Group 1 value, the whitespaces in Group 2 and an uppercased value in Group 3.